# Is there a way to code html pages with includes that is SEO friendly?

Tags: php, javascript, seo

I inherited a website with about 40 pages and the menus are static in the files as is the footer and header and are all html pages.  I was thinking about using JS document.write in a javascript include to isolate the code and write it inline.  After researching, it does not appear that SE's will see this and having SE's not find the menu links is not a good thing.  Is there anyway to do this with .html pages?  I am sure many of the pages have external links so i do not want to change them to php or asp.  I am thinking bout writing a php script that will rewrite the pages and swap in the included content.  Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: You could create a sitemap for the searchengines and link it from every page. The searchengines then should find all your content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most HTTP servers (IIS / Apache / Lighttpd etc) support [Server Side Includes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes)

```
<!--#include file="header.html" -->

// your content

<!--#include file="footer.html" -->
```

this would make your life easy ...

Comment: The problem is they are html pages.

Comment: @user999684 .... and the problem is ? these includes are mean for HTML pages - did you even read the link ? Quote `In order for a web server to recognize an SSI-enabled HTML file`

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option is to do a dynamic load from a database of keywords like:

```
<meta NAME="DESCRIPTION" CONTENT="<?php require('file_that_loads_desc_for_each_individual_page.php'); ?>" />
<meta NAME="KEYWORDS" CONTENT="<?php require('file_that_loads_keywords_for_each_individual_page.php'); ?>" />
```

Its messy to have to modify an `include` after `include`. You say your site has 40 pages currently --> imagine having to modify 40 different php includes!

This makes it easier to modify all your pages and keeps your code clean by just dynamically generating the keywords from a database and only having to modify the actual content in a row to change it on a page.

Comment: I wanted to make includes out of the header, footer and menus.  They would be static in the includes.

Answer (score 0):

In php you can add this to the .htaccess file and php will process the .html with the php engine as with .php files:

```
# Use PHP5 by default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php .html
```

Got this from [here](http://www.bluehostforum.com/showthread.php?20116-Can-PHP-pages-have-HTML-extension) I didn't test it now so cant guarantee the syntax but it dose work if you can change the .htaccess file on the server

Answer (score 0):

I would re-write them in php then set up 301 redirects in your .htaccess file to redirect spiders and visitors to the new locations.